# firefox addon: How to get url links in css

Tags: firefox-addon

I am currently porting over my google chrome extension over to firefox. My css file has url links to certain pictures the css uses. However, those are not loaded in the firefox addon. How to i make it so that my css files have the correct path to the proper assets?

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8;
    background: url('popup/source/overlay.png');
}
```

So i am at this point now

I have my chrome.manifest file as

```
 skin   firefox     fancybox     chrome/skin
```

i also have my file structure as the following

```
./chrome/
./chrome/skin/icon/{all the .png/.gif}
./chrome.manifest
./data/
./lib/
./package.json
./test/
```

with that, my css files are still are not loading with the following code.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8;
    background: url('chrome://firefox/skin/icon/overlay.png');
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Upload to github and show us. There are multiple ways. Did you try relative urls? If not upload and show it'll help us give u the easiest way.

Comment: How do I get relative urls in my css file when including them in my firefox addon?

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you would include some example CSS code which is not working for you.

Comment: okay, i added a small css snippet

Comment: If you put your stuff on github i can help you in 5 minutes and you can study how it was done. I don't know if you're doing bootstrap, overlay, or addonsdk. All of them can use similar methods, same methods, or unique methods like in addon sdk.

Comment: I prefer not to put this code on github, sorry noitdart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will use a `chrome://` URL to reference things within your extension.  They will generally look like:

```
`chrome://myExtensionName/content/...`
```

or if you have defined a skin for your extension:

```
`chrome://myExtensionName/skin/...`
```

You define what the `chrome://` URLs mean in your `chrome.manifest` file ([general info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Manifest_Files), [specific specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration)).

Here are some examples of CSS code which pull in images from within the Firefox release. They reference images contained in the user's currently defined skin.

The first defines an image for an element with the `toolbar-close-button` class.

```
.toolbar-close-button {
     list-style-image: url("chrome://global/skin/icons/Close.gif");
}
```

This defines the images used for a throbber (busy indicator) which can be turned on any off by adding, or removing the `busy=true` attribute:

CSS:

```
/**
 * Original source/idea from the Firefox release.
 * Modifications copyright 2014 by Makyen.
 * Released under the MPL 2.0. http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
 **/
/* ::::: throbber ::::: */
.c4w-throbber[busy="true"] {
  background: url("chrome://global/skin/icons/loading_16.png") center no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.c4w-throbber {
  background: url("chrome://global/skin/icons/notloading_16.png") center no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

For completeness here is JavaScript which will turn the throbber on and off (I made some quick changes to put it in a more generic format, those changes still need testing):

```
var Throbber = {
   /**
    * Original source/idea from the Firefox release.
    * Modifications copyright 2014 by Makyen.
    * Released under the MPL 2.0. http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
    **/

    /**
     * Tobggle throbber.
     * @param  id
     *         The DOM ID of the throbber element
     */
    toggleThrobber : function(id) {
        let throbberEl = document.getElementById(id);
        if(typeof throbberEl == "object") {
            if (throbberEl.hasAttribute("busy") ) {
                // Turn the throbber off.
                Throbber.throbberOff(id);
            } else {
                // Turn the throbber on.
                Throbber.throbberOn(id);
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Turn throbber off.
     * @param  id
     *         The DOM ID of the throbber element
     */
    throbberOff : function(id) {
        let throbberEl = document.getElementById(id);
        if(typeof throbberEl === "object") {
            if (throbberEl.hasAttribute("busy") ) {
                // Turn the throbber off.
                throbberEl.removeAttribute("busy");
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Turn throbber on.
     * @param  id
     *         The DOM ID of the throbber element
     */
    throbberOn : function(id) {
        let throbberEl = document.getElementById(id);
        if(typeof throbberEl == "object") {
            // Turn the throbber on.
            throbberEl.setAttribute("busy", "true");
        }
    }
}
```

Example minimal chrome.manifest file

```
content       myExtensionName                                     chrome/content/
```

Example directory structure:

```
./chrome
./chrome/content
```

A more complex chrome.manifest example:

```
content       myExtensionName                                     chrome/content/
locale        myExtensionName           en-US                     chrome/locale/en-US/
skin          myExtensionName           classic/1.0               chrome/skin/
content       myExtensionNameModules                              modules/
```

The separation of content and JavaScript Modules is merely for organization and is not required.

Directory structure example (nothing special about the directory names except: `./chrome/icons/default` if your extension uses non-default *window* icons and is ([unpacked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack) && ! [bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) && ! [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)) ):

```
./chrome
./chrome/content
./chrome/icons
./chrome/icons/default
./chrome/locale
./chrome/locale/en-US
./chrome/skin
./defaults
./defaults/preferences
./modules
```

Comment: I see, do you think you can give me an example of setting up the manifest file? I am getting lost in the instructions you linked too.

Comment: actually man, can you take a look at my edit? i am still having problems